# Check value exists in Array inside tagsManager validator method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using tagsManager plugin http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager/v3  to add certain tags inside Razor view and i am passing an int[] from controller to View using ViewBag 
The javascript code is like

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tm-input").tagsManager({
        delimiters: [9, 44], // tab,  comma . Can add Enter by adding 13 to this list , but form Post will occur
        hiddenTagListName: 'Students', //Use the property of the model as Hidden field to get the values at post 
        hiddenTagListId: 'Students',
        validator: function (value) {
            // var items = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.RollNos));
             var items = [ @(string.Join(", ", (int[])ViewBag.RollNos)) ];
             console.log(items);
              console.log(value);
              var res=items.indexOf(value);
             console.log(res);
             var res=$.inArray( value, items);
             console.log("**"+res);
             if(items.indexOf(value) >-1)
             {
                return true;
             }
             else{
                alert("Invalid roll NO");
                return false;
            }
       }
    });
});
```

In console what i can see is

```
[1, 3, 6, 7, 5, 2, 4]
1
-1
**-1
```

ie i am getting as the element 1 not exists in array [ using both jquery an djavascript methods]
Any insight to this error?

Comment: What is the value of `value`? Also, `indexOf` is not supported in all browsers. As you've tagged jQuery, you can try `$.inArray(items, value)`

Comment: I tried Jquery also 
var res=$.inArray( value.trim(), items);
             console.log("**"+res);
But getting -1. Also value of value parameter is getting as 1

Answer (score 0):

You are using `trim()` on the value which will return a string, the array contains integers so that comparison will fail. Remove the `trim` and it works:

```
var arr = [1, 3, 6, 7, 5, 2, 4];
var value = 1;

console.log('JS', arr.indexOf(value));
console.log('jQ', $.inArray(value, arr));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/szyctoeh/1/)

If you have to work with a string value, you need to convert that to an integer:

```
var value = "1";
console.log('JS', arr.indexOf(parseInt(value, 10)));
console.log('jQ', $.inArray(parseInt(value), arr));
```

Comment: i tried with removing the trim() as well . But still its returning -1 only. The question editted with complete initialization of tagsManager plugin.YES if i run from console things are working fine no issues , but from code its returning -1